# Trying to re-populate a table when select is changed

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to re-populate my `table` below when the `select` is `changed`?

I'm not sure how/if these 2 `controllers` can interact, even though they both live under the same `ng-app`.

```
<div class="inner" ng-app="fixturesApp">
    <h1 class="center">Upcoming matches</h1>

    <div ng-controller="leagueController">
        <form>
            <label>Choose league:</label>
            <select id="mySelect" ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-controller="tableController">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Home</th>
                        <th>Away</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="fixture in fixtures">
                        <td ng-cloak>{{ fixture.homeTeam.name }}</td>
                        <td ng-cloak>{{ fixture.awayTeam.name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my logic. Which populates the select with 4 `options` and sets a default value ..

```
var app = angular.module('fixturesApp', []);

app.controller('tableController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/fixtures?league=premier").success(function (response) {
        $scope.fixtures = response;
    });
});

app.controller('leagueController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '1', name: 'premier'},
      {id: '2', name: 'championship'},
      {id: '3', name: 'league1'},
      {id: '4', name: 'league2'}
    ],
    selectedOption: {id: '1', name: 'premier'} //This sets the default value to premiership
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `ng-change` on the league selection list, i.e.:

```
ng-change="getFixtures(data.selectedOption)"
```

You would have to move the service call up in `leagueController`:

**leagueController:**

```
$scope.getFixtures = function (league) {
    // set $scope.fixtures
};
```

<strike>As `tableController` is a child of `leagueController`, *fixtures* are inherited. If you have no other logic inside `tableController`, consider removing it.</strike>

Edit:
Didn't notice `tableController` is not a child but a sibling. It makes sense to have a controller responsible for both the dropdown and the table, i.e. to move `leagueController` one level up, but if your question is how to notify a sibling controller, you can do that by emiting an event from a parent `scope`, usually from the `rootScope`.

Comment: `tableController` is not a child of `leagueController`. its declared inside the next `div`

Comment: Right. Can't you move up leagueController so as it would be a parent of the table?